# Layout Nesting In Next Js

Tags: next.js

Okay, I got a serious issue here.

The Case Is-

I have got a specific Layout for Page A, B, and C. Now, on Page C, there'll be another Layout for Page C1, C2, and C3. How can I nest this layout within another layout?

In React Router 6, That'd be easily tackled with `<outlet/>`. How can I solve it in **NextJs**

Comment: Can you show us your `pages` folder structure and how you've currently implemented the layout logic?

Answer (score 1):

Next.js v13 makes it easy using [per-directory layouts](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/pages-and-layouts#nesting-layouts). All you need to do is use the `app` directory for your routes, and create `layout.tsx` / `layout.js` files in the appropriate places. This is an example directory structure as mentioned in the docs:

[image: nesting layouts example]

```
app
-- layout.tsx
-- page.tsx
-- dashboard
-- -- layout.tsx
-- -- page.tsx
```

The layout file should contain a component that returns children. Nested layouts will automatically wrap child layouts in their children prop.

> Layouts defined inside a folder (e.g. app/dashboard/layout.js) apply to specific route segments (e.g. acme.com/dashboard) and render when those segments are active. By default, layouts in the file hierarchy are nested, which means they wrap child layouts via their children prop.

Note that the `app` directory is currently in beta.